# Is there a way to add a canvas element as an image to svg

Tags: canvas, svg, d3.js

I have a jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gt7wQ/

What I'm trying to do is add the temporary canvas element that I just drew onto my svg board.
Is that possible?

What I'm trying to do now is:

```
svg.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", temp_canvas)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `toDataURL()` on your canvas element to generate a `data-uri`.

Also specify a width and height attribute for the d3 svg as well:

```
svg.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", temp_canvas.toDataURL())
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 300);
```

<kbd>**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/Gt7wQ/1/)**</kbd>

Note that this won't work if the content on the canvas is from a source of other origin than your page (ie. image drawn to canvas which orginated from a different domain).